# Declared include source C++ compile action invalidation

Tags: bazel

(From https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bazel-discuss/HEpui0DLvnA/RzuwICDmBgAJ)

Forgive me if this has been asked and answered by the group/devs.

The list of "Declared include source" files is a component of the action key for C++ compiles.

This means that the addition of a header-extension file to srcs or hdrs of a cc_* target results in the invalidation of all compile actions which can see the declared list contents (in the hdrs case, transitively).

Can anyone explain how this could be necessary, when include pruning should be providing the minimal set of possible invalidation sources for a compile?

Answer (score 2):

Reputation prevents me from commenting on your answer and the repost means that I don't own the question, but there is more to the problem than just a 're-validation':

Declared inclusion sources are transitively derived, resulting in action invalidation and reexecution (not simply re-validated, the definition of which is fuzzy at best for me) of all compiles in dependent targets.

The point of this post was to discuss (hence bazel-discuss) whether there is any way that previous compiled outputs could be affected, logistically, by *adding* (not discussing removal of) the definition of a header file, without changing any source related to the previous compilation.  The inputs set, which would have been pruned to match the used header files, should (must) be an accurate enough depiction of the only possible triggers for action reexecution.  The capacity of any compile to depend upon the newly added header is nil without further changes to the actual content of the input set of an action.

Comment: "Reputation prevents me from commenting on your answer and the repost means that I don't own the question" -- sorry about that, I didn't anticipate this problem.

Comment: By "re-validation" I meant that Bazel reruns the action, but if its outputs are the same as last time it ran, Bazel considers downstream actions (that depend on this file) to be up-to-date. I think adding a header file can affect the compilation, e.g. if a file with the same name is already included but found at a different include path. Example: you add your own "stdio.h" to `srcs`.

Comment: I recognize the difficulty of this with bazel's action cache and architecture, but this creates an unwieldy cross-section of 'could cause modification' targets.  While the stdio.h example is valid (though complicated with local/system quoted/angle bracket include paths), the practical limits of basenames, let alone resolved paths, are completely ignored, making the addition of my 'new_header.h' which does not appear in *any* existing available declared include lists ridiculously expensive.

Comment: Do you observe that everything that depends on your cc_library is rebuilt after you add new_header.h? Are you adding it to `srcs` or `hdrs`? If the former, and nothing includes this header, then Bazel should only rebuild this one rule, and notice that the resulting object file is the same as in the previous build, and not rebuild any rules depending on this one (unless they depend on other stuff that also changed). It may also happen that the header is picked up by a `glob` in that package, which the rebuilt targets depend on. Do you have a repro?

Answer (score 0):

When the rule's definition changes (you add a file to srcs/hdrs), Bazel must assume that change may affect the compilation result, even if none of the other files changed. (For example you just added a header that was missing before.)

If you rebuild the target Bazel reruns the compilation action. If the output of that (the object file) is the same as the last time Bazel ran the action, it's going to re-validate downstream actions without re-executing them.